# Oracle SQL CASE statement checking multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL and am trying to fulfill the following logic:
On PS_EMPLOYEES, if ADDRESS3 is not null and not equal to ' ', populate this field with ADDRESS2 else, populate this field with ADDRESS1.

I am able to get the following part working, but how do I make sure it isn't null too?

```
, ADDRESS_LINE1 = 
    SELECT (CASE WHEN t2.ADDRESS3 != ' ' THEN substr(t2.ADDRESS2, 1, 30) ELSE substr(t2.ADDRESS1, 1, 30) END)
    FROM PS_EMPLOYEES t2
    WHERE t2.EMPLID = PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL_T.EMPLID
```

Comment: I don't get the logic.  Why evaluate line 3 and return line 2 or 1 for line 1.  this is saying if line 3 of address is empty, then return line 2 of the address for line 1.  Otherwise if address 3 is empty return line 1 for line one.  Maybe you have some strange business rules though.

Comment: in Oracle, empty set and null evaluate the same so you could just trim(t2.address3) is not null (trim cuts out empty spaces) and since empty set and null are treated the same just check for null.

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  `!=` is going to return `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`, and `NULL` is treated as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine whatever conditions you like in a `CASE` statement using `AND` and `OR`

```
(CASE WHEN t2.address3 IS NOT NULL AND
           t2.address3 != ' '
      THEN substr( t2.address2, 1, 30 )
      ELSE substr( t2.address1, 1, 30 )
  END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get by with an or statement in your case clause

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t2.ADDRESS3 != ' ' or t2.ADDRESS3 is null THEN substr(t2.ADDRESS2, 1, 30) ELSE substr(t2.ADDRESS1, 1, 30) END)
```